# HoverBehaviorButton Still Exists after Removing Widget

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Python 3.4.4
Kivy: 1.9.1

I'm using this [hoverable.py](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/So0NMyLa6Vs)(file found at bottom) to create mouse_pos events for buttons to do custom animations.

However when I remove the associated widgets via clear_widgets, somehow the HoverButtons still exist, even without self.parent. It is imperative I remove this button, as I plan to extend this hover events to other widgets and don't want persisting invisible widgets.

Take a look at below and let me know what am I not understanding.

In short, I want to completely remove HoverButton and all its associated behaviors.

```html
#main.py 

from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable',  1)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from main_menu import MainMenu
from _map import Map

Builder.load_file('main_menu.kv')

class HoverBehaviorPersistance(App):

    boxlayout_main_menu = ObjectProperty(None)
    hover_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HoverBehaviorPersistance, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.content = BoxLayout()
        self.main_menu = MainMenu()
        self.content.add_widget(self.main_menu)

    def build(self):
        return self.content
        
    def begin(self):
        print("begin")
        self.test_map = Map()
        self.main_menu.boxlayout_main_menu.clear_widgets()
        self.main_menu.clear_widgets()
        self.content.clear_widgets()
        self.content.add_widget(self.test_map)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HoverBehaviorPersistance().run()
```

```html
#main_menu.py

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Initializing MainMenu")
        
    def open_settings(self):
        settings_popup  = SettingsPopup()
        settings_popup.open()
        
class SettingsPopup(Popup):
    pass
```

```html
#main_menu.kv

#: import HoverButton hover_widget_behavior

<MainMenu>
    boxlayout_main_menu:_boxlayout_main_menu
    hover_button:_hover_button
    orientation: 'vertical'
 
 AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
     anchor_y: 'center'
  
        BoxLayout:
            id:_boxlayout_main_menu
  orientation: 'vertical'
         spacing: 10
  padding: 10
  size_hint: .5, .8
   
  HoverButton:
                id:_hover_button
      text: 'begin'
      on_release: app.begin()
            HoverButton:
                text: 'settings'
                on_release: root.open_settings()
    
<SettingsPopup>
    id: popup_settings
 size_hint: 0.9, 0.6
 title: "Settings"
 GridLayout:
 
     cols: 2
  
     Label:
  text:'Settings #1'
     Slider:
         orientation: 'horizontal'
  value: 25
  max: 100
  min: 0
     Label:
  text: 'Settings #2'
     BoxLayout:
  orientation: 'horizontal'
     Label:
  text: 'Settings #3'
```

```html
#_map.py

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Map(BoxLayout):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Map, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Map initiated.")
  
        self.btn = Button(text="btn")
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
```

```html
#hover_widget_behavior.py

from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class HoverGUIBehavior(object):
    #__author__ = 'Olivier POYEN'
    """Hover behavior.

    :Events:
        `on_enter`
            Fired when mouse enter the bbox of the widget.
        `on_leave`
            Fired when the mouse exit the widget 
    """

    hovered = BooleanProperty(False)
    border_point= ObjectProperty(None)
    '''Contains the last relevant point received by the Hoverable. This can
    be used in `on_enter` or `on_leave` in order to know where was dispatched the event.
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_enter')
        self.register_event_type('on_leave')
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        super(HoverGUIBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
        pos = args[1]
        inside = self.collide_point(*pos)
        if self.hovered == inside:
            #We have already done what was needed
            return
        self.border_point = pos
        self.hovered = inside
        if inside:
            self.dispatch('on_enter')
        else:
            self.dispatch('on_leave')

    def on_enter(self):
        pass

    def on_leave(self):
        pass
        
class HoverButton(Button, HoverGUIBehavior):    
    
    # TODO: HoverButton somehow still exists even after removing parent and it's children
    def on_enter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm still here!")
        if not self.parent: # Find someway to remove itself
            print()
            print('self = ' + str(self))
            print("I'm definitely still here!")
            return
        self.ref_x = self.x
        self.ref_y = self.y
        
        self.anim = Animation(x = self.x -10 ,y = self.y - 10, duration=1.0, t='out_bounce') + Animation(x = self.x + 10, y = self.y + 10, duration=1.0, t='out_bounce')
        self.anim.repeat = True
        self.anim.start(self)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        if not self.parent: # Find someway to remove itself 
            print()
            print('self = ' + str(self))
            print("I'm definitely still here!")
            return
        if self.anim:
            self.anim.cancel(self)
            return_anim = Animation(pos = (self.ref_x, self.ref_y), duration = 0.35, t='out_bounce')
            return_anim.start(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue.

The issue was the fact that I didn't realize that I had to unbind functions when transitioning between different layouts.

To hover_widget_behavior.py, all I had to do was unbind itself(unbind the on_mouse_pos) if I removed it's parent (ex. if not self.parent:).

Now I am not getting on_mouse_pos whenever I remove/re-create they layout.

```html
#hover_widget_behavior.py

from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class HoverGUIBehavior(object):
    #__author__ = 'Olivier POYEN'
    """Hover behavior.

    :Events:
        `on_enter`
            Fired when mouse enter the bbox of the widget.
        `on_leave`
            Fired when the mouse exit the widget 
    """

    hovered = BooleanProperty(False)
    border_point= ObjectProperty(None)
    '''Contains the last relevant point received by the Hoverable. This can
    be used in `on_enter` or `on_leave` in order to know where was dispatched the event.
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.register_event_type('on_enter')
        self.register_event_type('on_leave')
        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
        super(HoverGUIBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
#==========================================================
        # Insert this statement to unbind itself its
        # parent does not exist
        if not self.parent:
            print("No self.parent")
            Window.unbind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
            return
#==========================================================
        pos = args[1]
        inside = self.collide_point(*pos)
        if self.hovered == inside:
            #We have already done what was needed
            return
        self.border_point = pos
        self.hovered = inside
        if inside:
            self.dispatch('on_enter')
        else:
            self.dispatch('on_leave')

    def on_enter(self):
        pass

    def on_leave(self):
        pass

class HoverButton(Button, HoverGUIBehavior):

    # TODO: HoverButton somehow still exists even after removing parent and it's children
    def on_enter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm still here!")
        if not self.parent: # Find someway to remove itself
            print()
            print('self = ' + str(self))
            print("I'm definitely still here!")
            return
        self.ref_x = self.x
        self.ref_y = self.y

        self.anim = Animation(x = self.x -10 ,y = self.y - 10, duration=1.0, t='out_bounce') + Animation(x = self.x + 10, y = self.y + 10, duration=1.0, t='out_bounce')
        self.anim.repeat = True
        self.anim.start(self)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        if not self.parent: # Find someway to remove itself 
            print()
            print('self = ' + str(self))
            print("I'm definitely still here!")
            return
        if self.anim:
            self.anim.cancel(self)
            return_anim = Animation(pos = (self.ref_x, self.ref_y), duration = 0.35, t='out_bounce')
            return_anim.start(self)
```